# how to upload quotation characters(") to BigQuery tables using API in Python script

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I need to upload a record from flat file to BigQuery table. 
Here is the sample file to be uploaded with delimiter as '$':

```
LCR_REF_OPS_DEPOSITS$amm_reporting_row:string,amm_section:string,amm_report_row_desc:string,amm_subsection_row:float,amm_subsection_desc:string$$csv$|$REF$1$"$$$$TRUE$Sample file$ALT REF
```

Problem is, in one of the column i need to upload quotation character(") and upload is failing because of it.
Here is the code snippet of API i am using :

```
bigquery_client = bigquery.Client()
dataset = bigquery_client.dataset('DATASET1')
table = dataset.table('SAMPLE_TAB')
# Reload the table to get the schema. 
table.reload()
with open('testfile.txt', 'rb') as source_file:
    # This example uses CSV, but you can use other formats. 
    # See https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/loading-data 
    job = table.upload_from_file(
        source_file, source_format='text/csv', field_delimiter='$')
```

Error encountered :

```
google.cloud.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 CSV table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1; errors: 1.
```

Could anyone suggest ways to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `"` character is [used as default](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#configuration.load.quote) by BigQuery to enclose records when reading data.

This might be a workaround for you then:

```
with open('testfile.txt', 'rb') as source_file:
    job = table.upload_from_file(
        source_file,
        source_format='text/csv',
        field_delimiter='$',
        quote_character='')
```

Comment: That's helpful. Thanks :)

Comment: I tried the above option, it works fine when I give quotes like (""), but if I want to give only double quotes (") it fails.

Comment: @GaurangR don't quite understand what you mean. Do you have an example?

Comment: I have sample data :
**Table Schema : **
`File_Type,FileSubType,quote_character,DynamicFlag,Description`

I have taken a variable and assigned it field values enclosed in single quotes as:
`var = 'File1' + '|' + 'File_Sub_Type' + '|' + '"' + '|' + 'TRUE' + '|' + 'File Description'`

writing this variable to csv file and loading this file into BigQuery Table.

Here, (") is double quotations (enclosed with two single quotation marks). I want to upload this quote character which I am unable to do.
Could you help?